# FlexArray can't connect to R

Tags: r

Whenever I run FlexArray, I face with this warning:

> FlexArray has detected statconnDCOM version 3.6-0B2 on your machine.
>   However, statconnDCOM failed to connect to R.
>   As a result, you will not be able to run algorithms on your data
>   in FlexArray, or to display certain plots.
>
> To fix this problem:
>   - Make sure you have R installed.
>   - Make sure that rscproxy package is installed in R.
>   - If you already have a version of R installed, run the program
>     RSetReg.exe located in 'bin' subdirectory of the installation
>     folder of the version of R you want to use with FlexArray.

I installed R version 3.2.0 and I can see "RSetReg.exe" located in 'bin' sub-directory of the installation folder of the version of my R but when I click on it, nothing happens.